# Getting "last list" in parent-child structure ( MYSQL/PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Good Hello,

I have created a simple tree structure.

This is the table structure

---

ID
is_parent_id

### category_name

if is_parent_id=0 , then those are the top level parents .

to get sub-categories (children) of any category (ie: ID=5) you just :
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE is_parent_id=5

simply enough right?

### now the problem I have is that if I want to go BACK . and get the last viewed list.

### remember that the tree is generated dynamically, and the user can theoretically be Hundred levels down.

is there any way I can have a dynamic "back" button that allows the user to back as far as he wants?

---

I'm trying to maybe pass the current clicked paren_ID into a tag clicked_id_1="X".., So I can use down the next level if the user clicks the back button, but I can't keep storing ALL THE CLICKED_IDS in all the levels, can I?

I'm really stuck and need someone that will look at this matter from outside the box.

I need the "back" button to work dynamically and practically. without the "number of levels," the user has gone through be a factor to its efficiency

Thank you

Comment: you can arrive this witch **CTE -  Common Table Expressions** see : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/

Comment: i did read that , but im not sure how i can implement that into my structure ? , keeping in mind that user can be 10 levels deep , how can i use CTE , to make the "back" buttom to get all the way back to level ONE ?

Comment: pls, post a sample table with the desired results then i post you the querys